# MongoDB mongod not running

Tags: mongodb, manjaro

I did a fresh install of manjaro and when trying to install mongodb I've failed to get mongod to run, although mongo cli runs normally. This is the error that I'm getting

```
2020-02-06T10:48:19.171-0300 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21061 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=matheus-pc
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-06T10:48:19.174-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIp: "--dbpath=data" }, storage: { journal: { enabled: false } } }
2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 W  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Found no addresses for HostNotFound: Could not find address for --dbpath=data:27017: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative)
2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

Any help is hugely appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Assuming the directory `/data/db` exists, the user account running the mongod process lacks permissions and cannot write to the directory `/data/db`.  See log output `IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db`

Answer (score 0):

> 2020-02-06T10:48:19.175-0300 W  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Found no addresses for HostNotFound: Could not find address for --dbpath=data:27017: SocketException: Host  not found (authoritative)

The dbpath looks like it might be incorrect, I'd double check that to see if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try giving permissions with
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db

Comment: sudo chown -R \`id -un\` /data/db